# How to make my kendo dropdown in core not auto hide when trying to select on item from it?

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui

I have a problem with my kendo dropdown.  I want to make my kendo dropdown in core not auto-hide when trying to select an item from it. I want to be able to filter information in DropDownTree control.

this is my code

```
<kendo-dropdownlist for="PatientId" style="width: 100%; height: 38px;"
                    datatextfield="Name"
                    datavaluefield="Id"
                    option-label="---اختار---"
                    fill-mode="FillMode.Outline"
                    filter="FilterType.Contains">
    <datasource type="DataSourceTagHelperType.Custom" server-filtering="true">
        <transport>
            <read url="@Url.Action("ServerFiltering_GetInputPatient", "Ajax")" />
        </transport>
    </datasource>
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

note: my dropdown in modal but if made it out of the modal, it`s working without any problems